# Pthread Thread-Local-Singleton, when to release the TLS Key?

Tags: singleton, pthreads, thread-local-storage

I implemented a kind of "thread local singleton" using pthread TLS, and i wondered how (and when) i could possibly delete the pthread_key_t in this case, because as it is now, the memory used by the TLS key will never be free'd.

The intended usage of this is to let a class A derive from ThreadLocalSingleton<A> which makes A a thread local singleton, assuming that A has only private constructors and ThreadLocalSingleton<A> is a friend of A.

Oh and also - do you see any problems with that implementation; did i overlook anything important?

```c
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class ThreadLocalSingleton
{
private:
    static pthread_key_t tlsKey;
    static pthread_once_t tlsKey_once;

    static void tls_make_key()
    {
        (void)pthread_key_create(&ThreadLocalSingleton::tlsKey, ThreadLocalSingleton::tls_destructor);
    }

    static void tls_destructor(void* obj)
    {
        delete ((T*)obj);
        pthread_setspecific(tlsKey, NULL); // necessary or it will call the destructor again.
    }

public:

    /*
     * A thread-local singleton getter, the resulted object must never be released,
     * it is auto-released when the thread exits.
     */
    static T* getThreadInstance(void)
    {
        pthread_once(&tlsKey_once, ThreadLocalSingleton::tls_make_key);
        T* instance = (T*)pthread_getspecific(tlsKey);
        if(!instance)
        {
            try
            {
                instance = new T;
                pthread_setspecific(tlsKey, instance);
            }
            catch (const char* ex)
            {
                printf("Exception during thread local singleton init: %s\n",ex);
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
};
template <class T>
pthread_key_t ThreadLocalSingleton<T>::tlsKey;
template <class T>
pthread_once_t ThreadLocalSingleton<T>::tlsKey_once = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;
```

Comment: According to Kerrisk in [The Linux Programming Interface: A Linux and UNIX System Programming Handbook](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1593272200), I believe you are using *Thread Specific Data* (`pthread_key_create` and friends) rather *Thread Local Storage* (`__thread` keyword on static and global variables).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation looks very elegant.

According to the [Open Group Specification of pthread_key_create](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/pthread_key_create.html), you don't have to set the reference to NULL in the destructor:

> An optional destructor function may be associated with each key value. At thread exit, if a key value has a non-NULL destructor pointer, and the thread has a non-NULL value associated with that key, the value of the key is set to NULL, and then the function pointed to is called with the previously associated value as its sole argument.

I think this also implies that the key object itself will be autodestroyed by pthread. You only have to take care of what's stored behind the key, which is precisely what your `delete ((T*)obj);` does.